# Is there an easily hackable open-source Tivo media server?

Tags: java, python, linux, tivo

Series 2 and later Tivos have a "Music on [computername]" option under "Music, Photos & Showcases" which lets you play music that's hosted on some other machine. This option seems to appear for each computer on the local network with a compatible server running. For example, a Windows PC running Tivo Desktop can show up if configured correctly. My NAS also has support for this. Neither of these servers are as configurable as I would like, however. (And the only Windows box in our house is a laptop, so it can't really be relied on as a server since it's asleep most of the time.)

Is there an easily hackable open-source Tivo media server (or library for building one)? I need something that can run on Linux, and I'd prefer something written in Python or Java.

I mostly care about being able to serve music (mp3 files), but supporting the "Photos on [computername]" thing would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this, but there's a package called [pyTiVo](http://pytivo.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/PyTivo) which claims to serve videos, music, and photos.  (Here's [a blog post](http://www.edsalisbury.net/linux/how-to-set-up-a-tivo-media-server-on-ubuntu-linux/) of how someone set it up in an old version of Ubuntu.)

Comment: Looks very promising. Thanks!

Comment: I finally got around to playing with this, and it works really well. Some of the code feels more complicated than it has to be, but overall I'm pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [JavaHMO](http://javahmo.sourceforge.net/) which is GPL. I haven't used it in ages but it should be worth investigating.

**Updated:**

Just after writing that I see that JavaHMO is now [Galleon](http://galleon.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HME/VLC Video Streamer](https://github.com/wmcbrine/hmevlc).  It's cross-platform Python and GPL 2.1 licensed.  Pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks. According to the documentation this is only for Series 3+ (rather than Series 2+), but might be useful to others.